# Python append for multiple lists

Tags: python

I've got a problem of appending elements in multiple lists. My program goes like this. where list is just a series of numbers.

```
for j in range(0, len(list)):
    if (int(list[j][4]) == 0 or int(list[j][:-4]) == 41601000000):
        filelist0.append(list[j])
    if (int(list[j][4]) == 1 or int(list[j][:-4]) == 41602000000):
        filelist1.append(list[j])
    if (int(list[j][4]) == 2 or int(list[j][:-4]) == 41603000000):
        filelist2.append(list[j])
    if (int(list[j][4]) == 3 or int(list[j][:-4]) == 41604000000):
        filelist3.append(list[j])
    if (int(list[j][4]) == 4 or int(list[j][:-4]) == 41605000000):
        filelist4.append(list[j])
    if (int(list[j][4]) == 5 or int(list[j][:-4]) == 41606000000):
        filelist5.append(list[j])
    if (int(list[j][4]) == 6 or int(list[j][:-4]) == 41607000000):
        filelist6.append(list[j])
    if (int(list[j][4]) == 7 or int(list[j][:-4]) == 41608000000):
        filelist7.append(list[j])
    if (int(list[j][4]) == 8 or int(list[j][:-4]) == 41609000000):
        filelist8.append(list[j])
```

This is ugly. Is there a way to write the above code in a line or two? Obvious I can iterate strings, but not for the name of the lists. (can't iterate filelist[m] for m in range(0, 9)).

Thanks!

Comment: Tip: Don't use `list` as a variable name. Subtle mayhem ensues.

Answer (score 3):

The following should be equivalent:

```
filelists = [filelist0, filelist1, filelist2, filelist3, filelist4,
             filelist5, filelist6, filelist7, filelist8]
for x in lst:
    for i, filelist in enumerate(filelists):
        if int(x[4]) == i or int(x[:-4]) == 41601000000 + i * 1000000:
            filelist.append(x)
```

Note that I renamed `list` to `lst`, it isn't a good idea to used built-in names for your variables.

Comment: +1, but there's no need for the `j` variable. A loop over `x in lst` would be even shorter.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `if int(x[4]) == i or ...`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python 2.7 you can actually use the map() function without a variable assigned, e.g.

```
>>> listdata = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list_o_lists = [ls0, ls1, ls2, ls3, ls4]
>>> map(lambda x, y: x.append(y), listdata, list_o_lists)
```

Hope this helps, thought it was a bit simpler than the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put the lists in a dict? You can use `defaultdict` to automatically create the item if it's not already in there. The increment number on the end is done by %d into a string then using `int` to convert back to a number. Still ugly, but there you go.

```
from collections import defaultdict

filelist = defaultdict(list)

for j in range(0, len(list)):
    for fl in range(0, 9) #0-8
        if (int(list[j][4]) == fl or int(list[j][:-4]) == int('4160%d000000' % fl+1)):
            filelist[fl].append(list[j])
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution with one list of lists

```
filelists = []

list = [[1,3,2,6,5,7,6],[3,5,7,8,5,5,4]]

for i in range(8):
    filelists.append([])
    for j in range(0, len(list)):
        if (int(list[j][4]) == i or int(list[j][-4]) == 41601000000):
            print 'added'
            filelists[i-1].append(list[j])
```

Result is

```
>>> filelists
[[], [], [], [], [[1, 3, 2, 6, 5, 7, 6], [3, 5, 7, 8, 5, 5, 4]], [], [], []]
```

Answer (score -2):

```
filelist = [[] for _ in range(9)]
for j, item in enumerate(item_list):
    for i in range(9):
        if (int(item[4])==i or
            int(item[-4])==int('4160{}000000'/format(i+1))
        ):
            filelist[i].append(j)
            break
```